# Vue - Ошибка при добавлении компонента

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Пытаюсь разобраться с Vue.js и возникла проблема при создании компонента. Не понимаю что не так и чего не хватает но все равно ловлю ошибку:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <mytag> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

(found in <Root>)
```

Index.html:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>vueTest</title>
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <!--<div class="app">-->
    <!--    <h2>{{ product }}</h2>-->
    <!--    <img :src="path " width="50px" height="50px" class="theIMG" :style="styless">-->
    
    <!--</div>-->
    
    <div id="anAp">
        <myTag></myTag>
    </div>
    
    <!--<button id="theButton">Press</button>-->
    <script src="vue.js"></script>
    <script src="action.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Action.js:

```
    Vue.component ("myTag",{
        name: 'myTag',
        template: '<p>Hello world!</p>'
    })
    
    new Vue({
        el: '#anAp',
        data: {
    
        }
    
    
    })
```

Помогите исправить пожалуйста, я новичок в Vue.js((

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка говорит, что компонент с именем `mytag` не найден из чего следует, что необходимо разобраться с именованием компонентов во `Vue`.

Цитирую официальное руководство - [Именование компонентов](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2):

> Имя, которое вы даёте компоненту, может зависеть от того, где вы собираетесь его использовать. При использовании компонента непосредственно в DOM (в отличие от строковых шаблонов или однофайловых компонентов), мы настоятельно рекомендуем следовать [правилам W3C](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#valid-custom-element-name) для именования пользовательских тегов (все символы в нижнем регистре, должен содержать дефис). Это позволит избежать конфликтов с текущими и будущими HTML-элементами.

[Дополнительные рекомендации](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F)

и рабочий пример:

```js
Vue.component("my-tag", {
  name: 'myTag',
  template: '<p>Hello world!</p>'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#anAp',
  data: {

  }


})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>vueTest</title>
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="anAp">
    <my-tag></my-tag>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
  <script src="action.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но у меня в коде почему то такой код работает только когда во vue.component пишу так "myTag" а когда объявляю тег я пишу "my-Tag", почему же так? а когда я во vue.Component пишу "my-Tag" на сайте выдается такая же ошибка